# how to print string twice in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

Im new in assembly so maybe this is a noob question. How can I print a string twice in one line. I have this code, but it only prints once. this is a homework, but I don't want to cheat, I just want to know what is wrong with my code.

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack
.data
     prompt1 db 13,10,"Enter a String: $"   
     prompt2 db 13, 10, "$"
     str1 db 30 dup("$")
.code
main proc
  mov ax,@data
  mov ds,ax
  mov es, ax

  lea dx,prompt1                
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  mov byte ptr str1, 30     
  mov dx, OFFSET str1
  mov ah,0ah
  int 21h

  lea dx,prompt2                
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  mov SI, 0002                  
  lea dx, str1[SI]
  int 21h
  int 21h

  mov ax,4c00h
  int 21h

main endp
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printed twice, but the two copies overlap. `int21/0a` will terminate the input buffer with a `CR` character **only** (don't ask why) which, when printed just moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, but does not advance to the next line. You can just print another line feed between them:

```
  mov SI, 0002                  
  lea dx, str1[SI]
  int 21h

  lea dx, prompt2                
  int 21h

  lea dx, str1[SI]
  int 21h
```

Re-reading your question, you seem to want to print it twice on the same line. In that case, chop off the trailing `CR`:

```
movzx si, byte ptr [str1+1]   ; the length
mov byte ptr [str1+si+2], '$' ; chop off CR
lea dx, [str1+2]
int 21h
int 21h
```

Comment: is it possible that I can print them in one line like they are concatenated?

Comment: That's what the second block does.